# $n$th derivative of $\sin(\cos(x))$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $$f_n(x)=\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sin(\cos(x))$$
>
> Prove there are an infinite number of $n$ such that the global maximum of $f_n(x)$ is an integer.

I looked this up online and it seems like this is related to exponential generating functions, but I don't know enough about them. How does this work?

Comment: There is a well-known [expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%E2%80%93Anger_expansion) for $\sin(\cos x)$ (and other similar combinations). But it is not evident to me that this is actually useful here.

Comment: By comment of user @Semiclassical we get: $$\frac{d^n}{dx^n}\sin(\cos(x))=\sum _{j=1}^{\infty } -2 (-1)^j (-1+2 j)^n J_{-1+2 j}(1) \cos \left(\frac{n \pi }{2}+(-1+2 j) x\right)$$

Comment: @NoahD.: The nth derivative can be expressed using the partial Bell polynomial. I am not sure it helps with the prove part of the question.